# I have a 720p laptop but I need to record my screen on 1080p

Tags: video, display, resolution, high-definition, screen-recorder

I need to record a demo for one of my applications to submit on windows store and their requirement is that the video file resolution should be **1920*1080** but the problem is maximum resolution my laptop supports is **1366*720** is there a software or a way where I can record the video and it outputs 1080p video? if not than is there a workaround this?

I mean I wont mind recording my laptop screen in 720p output and then put the output video in a 1080p frame In a **video editor** which can output my video in 1080p resolution ( the frame will probably be a laptop **frame** and in place of its screen my video will be playing ). is that possible? if yes then which software can do that?

Comment: Connect an external screen? Or run a VirtualBox on FHD and enable scaling.

Comment: if I connect my laptop with HDMI cable to a TV, then can I get the resolution of the TV, instead of the laptop ?

Comment: Yes you can. Just type windows+p and select "Extend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer dedicated video cards support [Virtual Super Resolution](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/VSR.aspx) for AMD and [Dynamic Super Resolution](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/dsr/technology) on NVIDIA.

Also you can use a VirtualBox, set it's resolution to your desired, and activate scaling.

Another way would be to connect an external screen which allows the needed resolution.